# How to create two Ace Editors side by side

Tags: html, css, ace-editor

I am using the Ace Editor. I want to have two editors side-by-side on taking up the whole screen, but I am having trouble getting them to display. The only way the editors will display is with this code:

```
.editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

However, this css also stops me from setting the width of the editors to 50% and moving one of them to the right side of the screen.

I am beginner with css, so help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Any way to position two div elements side by side works with ace too.
With absolute positioning you can use:

```
.editor1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.editor2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Or if you target the modern browsers you can use display flex or grid

Answer (score 1):

Had the same need and solved it like this:

```css
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>

    <AceEditor style={{ flex: 1, height: "250px" }} ...restPropsEditor1 />

    <AceEditor style={{ flex: 1, height: "250px" }} ...restPropsEditor2/>

</div>
```

EDIT: note the style attribute surrounded by `{{` is because I am using react. If you are not, just replace `{{` `}}` with `"` and remove the inner quotes